# C++ factory of a class that specializes a templated superclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, matrix, factory

I'm developing a C++ framework for mathematical optimization and I'm struggling to find a good design for my sparse matrix representations.
Basically:

- I have two sparse matrix representations: types A and B ;
- I have (say) four linear solvers, Alan, Alicia, Beth and Benjamin. Alan and Alicia works exclusively with A matrices, Beth and Benjamin with B matrices ;
- I'd like to template my code so that choosing a linear solver at runtime sets the type of all the matrices (type A or B) in the rest of the code (so that the matrix of the linear system is generated directly in the right format).

I tried the following (simplified) code:

```
template <class MatrixType>
class LinearSolver {
   virtual void factorize(const MatrixType& matrix) = 0;
}

class LinearSolverAlan: public LinearSolver<MatrixTypeA> {
   void factorize(const MatrixTypeA& matrix) override;
}

class LinearSolverAlicia: public LinearSolver<MatrixTypeA> {
   void factorize(const MatrixTypeA& matrix) override;
}

class LinearSolverBeth: public LinearSolver<MatrixTypeB> {
   void factorize(const MatrixTypeB& matrix) override;
}

class LinearSolverBenjamin: public LinearSolver<MatrixTypeB> {
   void factorize(const MatrixTypeB& matrix) override;
}
```

The common supertype of the solvers is the template type `LinearSolver`, so I templated the factory as well:

```
template<class MatrixType>
class LinearSolverFactory {
public:
   std::unique_ptr<LinearSolver<MatrixType> > create(const std::string& solver_name) {
     if (solver_name == "alan") {
        return std::make_unique<LinearSolverAlan>();
     }
     else if (...) {
        ...
     }
   }
};
```

Then on a higher level, I call `LinearSolverFactory::create()` with the right solver name and template parameter.

However it won't compile (`std::unique_ptr<LinearSolverAlan>` cannot be converted to a `std::unique_ptr<LinearSolver<MatrixTypeA> >`). I'm not good enough at templates to see whether the problem can be fixed.

Thanks for your help :)

Charlie

Comment: both branches must be valid, but only one of them is at the same time. Why do you choose which type via the template parameter and via the string parameter? Isnt one of them sufficient to decide which type of solver the factory should return?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The linear solvers are third-party codes and there's potentially more than 2. They each use either A or B matrices. That's why I gave them names ; we choose the solver, which in turns should fix the matrix type.

Comment: but you can only call `LinearSolverFactory<TypeA>::create("alan")` and only `LinearSolverFactory<TypeB>::create("beth")`, the string seems to be superfluous, or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Templates and types are a compile-time thing. You can't have a matrix of "unknown" type transforms to the right matrixtype depending on a runtime choice of a solver. Either you can make the choice at compile-time, and the string with the name can be thrown away. Or you can make the choice at runtime, and use polymorphism.

Comment: what super said, but you are already choosing the matrix type at compile time via the template parameter. Maybe adding an example of how you plan to use the factory would help to clarify

Comment: Yes, there's redundancy. But the template parameter alone does not fully determine the solver (both solvers Beth and Benjamin use the matrix type B). I'll edit my original message to suggest that there are more than 2 solvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearSolverAlan` and `LinearSolverBeth` do not share a common base, because `LinearSolver<MatrixTypeA>` and `LinearSolver<MatrixTypeB>` are two unrelated types.

You can use either `if constexpr` to discard the branches that are not used in the specific instantation of the factory or specialize the whole factory:

```
template <typename MatrixType>
struct Factory;

template <> 
struct Factory<MatrixTypeA> {
   std::unique_ptr<LinearSolver<MatrixTypeA> > create(const std::string& name) {
         // select a LinearSolve<MatrixTypeA> and return it
   }
};

template <> 
struct Factory<MatrixTypeB> {
   std::unique_ptr<LinearSolver<MatrixTypeB> > create(const std::string& name) {
         // select a LinearSolver<MatrixTypeB> and return it
   }
};
```

Another alternative is to make `LinearSolver<MatrixTypeB>` and `LinearSovler<MatrixTypeB>` inherit from a common (non template) base class.

Comment: Beautiful! The specialized factory did the trick, thanks a lot.